# Adding to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'am trying to input som Flight information to Dictionary C# console.
But I don't know how to add those to my Dictionary.I want to store by flight number (I want flight number as a KEY). Here is my class and the hole code

```
 public class Flight
    {
        public int FlightNr;
        public string Destination;
    }

        int FlNr;
        string FlDest;
        List<Flight> flightList = new List<Flight>();

        do
        {

            Console.Write("Enter flight nummer (only numbers) :");
            FlNr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter destination :");
            FlDest = Console.ReadLine();

            flightList.Add(new Flight() { FlightNr = FlNr, Destination = FlDest });


        } while (FlNr != 0); 

       // create Dictionary
       Dictionary<int, Flight> dictioneryFlight = new Dictionary<int, Flight>();

      // My question is How to add those flights in my Dictionary ?

        dictioneryFlight.Add( I don't know what to input here);
```

Or is something wrong with my other code? something I missed? Thank you in advance! 
 .

Comment: What do you want to use for the key? The flight number? You need to specify.

Comment: @itsme86 Yes flight number , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the number as key for your dictionary then you don't need a list of flights but you can use directly the dictionary

```
    Dictionary<int, Flight> dictioneryFlight = new Dictionary<int, Flight>();
    do
    {

        Console.Write("Enter flight nummer (only numbers) :");
        // Always check user input, do not take for granted that this is an integer            
        if(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out FlNr))
        {
            if(FlNr != 0)
            {
                // You cannot add two identical keys to the dictionary
                if(dictioneryFlight.ContainsKey(FlNr))
                    Console.WriteLine("Fly number already inserted");
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter destination :");
                    FlDest = Console.ReadLine();

                    Flight f = new Flight() { FlightNr = FlNr, Destination = FlDest };
                    // Add it
                    dictioneryFlight.Add(FlNr, f);
                 }
             }   
        }
        else
           // This is needed to continue the loop if the user don't type a 
           // number because when tryparse cannot convert to an integer it
           // sets the out parameter to 0.
           FlNr = -1;

    } while (FlNr != 0);
```

Comment: +1 Addresses addition of flight 0 erroneously being added and prevents duplicate flight information from being added.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a dictionary out of your list of flights, you can use `ToDictionary()`.

```
var dict = flightList.ToDictionary(f => f.FlightNr);
```

You can do it without LINQ like so:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Flight>();
foreach (var flight in flightList)
    dict.Add(flight.FlightNr, flight);
```

As others have mentioned, you can skip having a `List<Flight>` altogether and just add directly to the dictionary when they're created instead.

One thing you might want to consider is checking if `FlNr` is `0` right after you parse the user input and break out of the loop right away if it is. Otherwise you'll end up with flight information for flight number `0` in your list/dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely sure but I think you meant to store by flight number like

```
    //declare this before your loop starts
    Dictionary<int, Flight> dictioneryFlight = new Dictionary<int, Flight>();

   //Add to dictionary in your loop
   dictioneryFlight.Add(FlNr, new Flight() { FlightNr = FlNr, Destination = FlDest });
```